# Titan db no documents getting created on elastic search even index is configuration options enabled

Tags: graph, titan

Here is the configuration options i am using.

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=192.168.56.121
storage.cassandra.keyspace=graphs
cache.db-cache = false
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=192.168.56.122
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
index.search.index-name=graphs

TitanGraph graph = GraphFactory.getInstance().getGraph();
TitanManagement mgmt = null;
try {
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    PropertyKey name = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Schema.NAME);
    if (name == null) {
        name = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Schema.NAME).dataType(String.class).make();

    }
    TitanGraphIndex graphIndex = mgmt.getGraphIndex("byName");

if (graphIndex == null) {
    IndexBuilder builder = mgmt.buildIndex("byName", Vertex.class).addKey(name);
    builder.buildCompositeIndex();
}

PropertyKey id = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Schema.ID);
if (id == null) {
    id = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Schema.ID).dataType(Long.class).make();
}

PropertyKey sourceType = mgmt.getPropertyKey(Schema.SOURCE_TYPE);
if (sourceType == null) {
    sourceType = mgmt.makePropertyKey(Schema.SOURCE_TYPE).dataType(String.class).make();
}

TitanGraphIndex uniqueIndex = mgmt.getGraphIndex("uniqueIndex");

if (uniqueIndex == null) {
    IndexBuilder builder = mgmt.buildIndex("uniqueIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(id).addKey(sourceType);
    builder.unique().buildCompositeIndex();
}

// Edges
EdgeLabel deps = mgmt.getEdgeLabel("deps");

if (deps == null) {
    deps = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("deps").multiplicity(Multiplicity.SIMPLE).make();
}

RelationTypeIndex  depsIndex = mgmt.getRelationIndex(deps, "depsIndex");

if(depsIndex == null) {
    depsIndex = mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(deps, "depsIndex", Direction.BOTH, Order.decr);
}

mgmt.commit();


// Re index the existing data
if (reIndexData) {
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("uniqueIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
    mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byName"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
    deps = mgmt.getEdgeLabel("deps");
    mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getRelationIndex(deps,"depsIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
        mgmt.commit();
    }

} catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    if (mgmt != null) {
        mgmt.rollback();
    }
}
```

I have created lots of documents and every thing is working fine. But when i observed the number document available in the elastic search is 0.

I am wondered whether titan db really using the elastic search or not.

Any idea what i am missing here ? And why documents are not getting created in elastic search.

And i also tried the belown configuration  as well but no luck

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=192.168.56.121
storage.cassandra.keyspace=graphs
cache.db-cache = false
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20

index.graphs.backend=elasticsearch
index.graphs.hostname=192.168.56.122
index.graphs.elasticsearch.client-only=true
index.graphs.index-name=graphs
```

Answer (score 2):

**Titan uses storage backend (cassandra/hbase) for Composite Index and index backend (Solr/Elastic Search) for Mixed Index**

> Mixed indexes retrieve vertices or edges by any combination of previously added property keys. Mixed indexes provide more flexibility than composite indexes and support additional condition predicates beyond equality. On the other hand, mixed indexes are slower for most equality queries than composite indexes.
>
> Unlike composite indexes, mixed indexes require the configuration of an indexing backend and use that indexing backend to execute lookup operations. Titan can support multiple indexing backends in a single installation. Each indexing backend must be uniquely identified by name in the Titan configuration which is called the indexing backend name.

In you schema you are creating only composite index. That's why there is not data in ElasticSearch.

Here is a example how to create a mixed index :

```
IndexBuilder builder = mgmt.buildIndex('byName', Vertex.class).addKey(name);
builder.buildMixedIndex("search");
mgmt.commit();
```

[Read More](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html)

Source : http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for give quick respone. And it is clear my doubts on the mixed index as well.

Comment: Mostly my data retrieval starts with and vertex which will be uniquely identified by  ID, SOURCETYPE. And i have created uniquekey as well as composite key in combination with those two attributes. does those enough or do i need to make any changes  to make it faster response

Comment: It is enough if you want to get vertex by ID and sourceType. But If you want to get vertex by only sourceType then it will be inefficient. You have to create index based on your query.